# `gn gen` gives `ERROR Need exactly one build directory to generate`

Tags: c++, gn

I was trying to follow google skia official build guide. The only thing i managed to do was clone skia from github. I don't understand need of deepot_tools. Then I tried to used GN but it gives me following error :

```
C:\Users\aslaf\skia>gn gen out/Shared --args='is_official_build=true is_component_build=true'

ERROR Need exactly one build directory to generate.
I expected something more like "gn gen out/foo"
You can also see "gn help gen"
```

I feel helpless. Maybe there exist person that has compiled skia on windows and could share some hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to run it in Windows Command Prompt that is not able to handle single quotation marks. `gn` gets the four arguments:

```
gen
out/Shared
--args='is_official_build=true
is_component_build=true'
```

Therefore it treats `out/Shared` and `is_component_build=true'` as two output directories. Try this

```
gn gen out/Shared --args="is_official_build=true is_component_build=true"
```

Or

```
gn gen out/Shared "--args=is_official_build=true is_component_build=true"
```

Or wrtie the file out/Shared/args.gn:

```
is_official_build=true 
is_component_build=true
```

and run

```
gn gen out/Shared
```